# Efficent way to watch a SQL table for new inserts

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a push service that inserts incoming data into a SQL table, i need to make an application that would be listening to this table to see for the new incoming data.

Is there a way to be listening to this table without having to be constantly SELECT ing the database for new changes? and if there is no use for this data shoud i just delete the row after reading it or is it better to do a periodical clean?

---

### UPDATE2

---

This is my actual code which is not giving me any notifications on an insert to the table, am i doing something wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Navman_SPI_Service
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        String passAvl = Properties.Settings.Default.AVLPass;
        String usuarioAvl = Properties.Settings.Default.AVLuser.ToString();
        String servidor = Properties.Settings.Default.Server.ToString();
        String DataB = Properties.Settings.Default.DB.ToString();
        String SQLuser = Properties.Settings.Default.DBuser.ToString();
        String SQLpass = Properties.Settings.Default.DBpassword.ToString();
        SqlCommand dependencyCommand = new SqlCommand();
        String connectionString = "";


        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public String getQuery()
        {
            return "SELECT MessageID FROM dbo.navman_ic_api_message WHERE Proccessed IS NULL";
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            dependencyCommand.CommandText = getQuery();
            connectionString = "Data Source=";
            connectionString += servidor + ";Initial Catalog=FOO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=";
            connectionString += SQLuser + ";Password=";
            connectionString += SQLpass + ";Initial Catalog=" + DataB;

            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                var logging = new StringBuilder();
                var filePath = @"c:\temp\log.txt";
                String timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy:MM:dd][HH:mm:ss]");
                logging.Append(timestamp + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + connectionString + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + f.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, logging.ToString());
            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Initialization();
                dependencyStarter();
                var logging = new StringBuilder();
                var filePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
                String timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy:MM:dd][HH:mm:ss]");
                logging.Append(timestamp + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "SUCCESS" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                File.AppendAllText(filePath, logging.ToString());
            }

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Termination();
        }

        void dependencyStarter()
        {
            // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

            // Create a new SqlCommand object.
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(getQuery(),con))
            {

                // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(dependencyCommand);
                // Maintain the refence in a class member.

                // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
                dependency.OnChange += new
                   OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

                // Execute the command.
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Process the DataReader.
                }
            }
        }
        void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
            var logging = new StringBuilder();
            var filePath = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
            String timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy:MM:dd][HH:mm:ss]");
            logging.Append(timestamp + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + sender.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, logging.ToString());
        }
        void Termination()
        {
            // Release the dependency.

            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        }
        void Initialization()
        {
            // Create a dependency connection.
            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sorry i thought i said it, SQL server

Comment: Does your RDBMS support [triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger)?

Comment: @PM77-1 i ma using Microsoft SQL Server Express V 11.0.5058.0, i belive so, but im kind of noob dont know how they work

Comment: Can each record be deleted immediately after it is read by the application? Or is there some conditional logic applied where some rows can be deleted but others can't regardless of being read (or "heard") from your listener application?

Comment: its just a buffer table so the rows that wont have logic applied to it can also be deleted, I just need to read some columns from the row and do some logic if some specific info is in it. else is trach for me.

Comment: you could create a trigger that acts upon INSERTS, and make it also insert new rows into a different table, who's only purpose would be to hold new records for your application to read from.
Your application can then read these new records, and when its done processing, delete them from this table.

this keeps your store table clean, and your application wont bog down y our server by running queries on the big table.

your app will check this table based on a timer... that way, if your app needs to be shutdown, it can always resume from where it left off, sine the data will handle itself.

Comment: Start your eduction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx).

Comment: curious - how fast does the listener app need to be aware of the new info - ASAP, within seconds, or within minutes? how frequently do you plan to poll for new data from the listener application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a SqlDependency.  [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx<br)

I've used these in a number of projects and they seem to work pretty well.  This uses QueryNotifications which is part of the SQL Server Service Broker.

If the Broker is not already active, you will have to enable it.  Get a DBA to run something like the following:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER;
GO
```

Sample code from the article:

```
void Initialization()
{
    // Create a dependency connection.
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, queueName);
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.

    // Create a new SqlCommand object.
    using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone FROM dbo.Shippers", 
        connection))
    {

        // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
        SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);
        // Maintain the refence in a class member.

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // Execute the command.
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

// Handler method
void OnDependencyChange(object sender, 
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
  // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
}

void Termination()
{
    // Release the dependency.
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString, queueName);
}
```

Basically, you setup a callback in SQL Server that gets called anytime the results for the given query change.  Then it's up to you to do something about it.

You'll probably want to have a column on the table so you can tell if the data's new or not.  Something like "CreateDate" or "Processed".  Exclude that from the dependency query.  Then you can use it later to grab only the new stuff.

I should note that if the table is changing frequently, it might be better to go with polling periodically and just grabbing all the changes as a single batch instead of trying to handle them one at a time.  SqlDependency is great for refreshing cached data.  It's not great for processing a table that's being used as a transaction queue.

I wouldn't delete the data when you're done.  Just ignore it in the next query or maybe move it to an archive table.  Deleting information is generally a bad idea in case you need to troubleshoot it later.

Comment: agree to avoid deletions - you will eventually regret it. if you have space constraints (sql express v8+ is limited to 10GB), you can schedule a monthly purge/archive job.

Comment: so this is avoiding the SQL trigger right? it would be done through the application?

Comment: @PatricioLlaguno Under the hood I believe it still creates a trigger.  You just don't have to manage it.  The trigger is created and dropped automatically.

Comment: @sarme, SqlDependency uses QueryNotifications, not a trigger, to detect data changes.  QueryNotifications uses SQL Server Service Broker infrastructure to deliver a change notification message when the results have changed.

Comment: @DanGuzman Ah.  That makes sense.  Thanks.  Will probably have to have a DBA enable the broker service then.

Comment: @sarme just to clarify, in that example i should only call SomeMethod once right? when ever i want to bond the trigger to an SQL query, did i understand this correctly?

Comment: @PatricioLlaguno Right.  Call it once to setup the dependency.  Then OnDependencyChange will get called when a change occurs.

Comment: @sarme Inside OnDependecyChange is where i should place a proccesed date to the rows? but won't that trigger again the onDependencyChange? since my query would be all rows that have null value on that column. or am i missing something?

Comment: @PatricioLlaguno If the column that stores the processed date ("ProcessedDate" or whatever) is not included in the SqlCommand you're passing to the SqlDependency, it shouldn't trigger the change event.

Comment: @sarme just a last question, your help has been really usefull, what just queueName should be my query? or what type of variable is this?

Comment: @PatricioLlaguno This is the name of the specific Service Broker queue to use, if required.  If you leave this out (or pass null), then the default queue is used.  Honestly, all I've ever done is use the default queue.  Check here for more details on the Start method: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224871(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @sarme for some reason it didnt trigger anything, is the order on to when i start the dependency important? also i saw some examples where once triggered the dependency has to be rebinded.

Comment: i just posted the code i am actually using, no more pseudo code, is it right? since i am getting no call.

Comment: @PatricioLlaguno You're starting to get outside the scope of your original question.  If you have problems with a specific implementation of SqlDependency, you'd probably be better off asking a new question.  However, it looks like the query you are using to initialize the dependency will only watch the MessageID column and only for rows that have NULL in the processed column.  I think the WHERE clause might be tripping you up.  Try it without the "WHERE Proccessed IS NULL" clause.